# django: issue navigating from one page to another

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to run a django project on my system.

my landing page url is **localhost/landing_page/**

To navigate from landing_page to another_page, in the <landing_page>.html i'm using:

```
<a href='xxx/another_page.html'> click here </a>
```

it's getting redirected to **'localhost/landing_page/xxx/another_page.html'** and throwing an error instead of getting redirected to **'localhost/xxx/another_page.html'**.

how do i direct it to 'localhost/xxx/another_page.html' ?

Comment: Did you create that particular endpoint in django?

Comment: Show us your urls.py. You may want to read about [url dispatching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) in django.

Comment: I think you didn't create the endpoint in your urls.py. Show us your urls.py. BTW, Django doesn't serve the html files directly from your templates directory, you have to create the endpoint first.

Answer (score 0):

try complete path:
instead of

```
<a href='xxx/another_page.html'> click here </a>
```

write

```
<a href='https://localhost/xxx/another_page.html'> click here </a>
```